# while app kill/terminate how to call a service for new updates in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to call a service continuously to check the new created event location to hit the server when app kill/terminate, because I want to fetch near by event location push notification with in 500m. 
But I am unable to call any service while app kill. But in background it's working fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527972/location-update-even-when-app-is-killed-terminated

Comment: You cannot run code in your app when your app is not running

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Location update even when app is killed/terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527972/location-update-even-when-app-is-killed-terminated)

Answer (score 1):

You can check this -> [Scheduling a Notification Locally from Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please read the question carefully

Comment: Thank you, for your reference, but while I am killing the app at the moment new event creating from back office/ backend end then how it will get & notify. I need to call the service/API to get the list of event. then only I can set the notification.
So while app in kill/terminate stage how to call a service to get the list of event.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly follow this json to get silent push notification which will wake your application if killed otherwise in the background you will get didReceiveRemoteNotification method trigger for more information and video please check [More Detail](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/silent-remote-notifications-with-swift-and-firebase/)

For testing it you can send silent notification from the postman with,

- https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send POST Request
- In Headers add two field
- Authorization: key=Firebase server key
- Content-Type :    application/json

Select Body -> Raw -> Json payload

```
{
    "content_available":true,
    "priority":"high",
    "data" : { 
        "article" : "12212121"
    },
    "to" : "eqZ_xx:APA91bxxxxZvAZF05J1-Vv5HrIU6cXVQdq8GExxxg-DWjVU0b8Ci36AWV0QrbsjKUWxxc1Q-vjrGclrEqZmMxhYMKriQFJQcmN5aBZX45Kht_PR86O_iaW7pzSxAFH"
}
```